# android realm inport csv with many to many relationship

Tags: android, csv, realm

I create an android app with two Object

```
class Dog extends RealmObject {
    int id;
    String name;
}

class Person extends RealmObject {
    int id;
    String name;
    RealmList<Dog> dogs;
}
```

I want to import data from two csv file as follow

Dog.csv 
id, person_id, name
1, 1, Pug
2, 1, Goo
3, 2, Gao

Person.csv
id, name
1, Mr A
2, Msr B

That mean there are two people named Mr A and Msr B. Mr A has two dogs named Pug and Goo. Mrs B has one dog named Gao. 
How can I import data and fetch dogs list with correct data?

Answer (score 0):

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        List<Person> persons = readPersonsFromCsv();
        realm.insertOrUpdate(persons);
        List<Dog> dogs = readDogsFromCsv();
        for(Dog dog : dogs) {
            Dog managedDog = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(dog);
            int personId = dog.getPersonId();
            Person person = realm.where(Person.class).equalTo("id", personId).findFirst();
            if(person != null) {
                person.getDogs().add(managedDog);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought this solution but the bad point here is list of Person and Dogs will too big and take much of machine RAM? Beside that, each dog we have to re-find person, so, performance is not good.

Comment: Insertion can be optimized by saving the object directly through a single unmanaged object and using `insert()` (for person), but the query mapping for dogs is unavoidable.